# How do I use a compass-generated sprite for generated content?

Tags: sprite, compass-sass

Is it possible to use a compass-generated sprite to replace the icon path below?

`a:before {
  content: url(/pathto/icon.png);
}`

Although I can work out how to get the sprite path in there, I don't know if it's possible to get the correct bit of the sprite showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't load the sprite map as "content". Set content to " ", load the sprite as a background, and control it the way you would with any other text/image-replacement sprite.

```
a:before {
  @include <map>-sprite(<icon>);
  @include sprite-dimensions(<map>, <icon>);
  content: " ";
}
```

Where `<map>` and `<icon>` are replaced by your specific sprite-map and icon names.

Comment: Great! Had to use `<map>-sprite-dimensions(<icon>) `, though